# Avoid redirect in Module FrontController

Tags: php, redirect, model-view-controller, controller, prestashop

I am building an api for my PrestaShop module using a module FrontController.

```
class mymoduleModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function init()
    {
       echo "Hello world"; 
    }
}
```

The controller runs fine under `mydomain.com/index.php?fc=module&module=mymodule&controller=api`

However.. When I change shop domain to for example `mynewdomain.com`, PrestaShop automatically redirects me from `mydomain.com/index.php?fc=module&module=mymodule&controller=api` to `mynewdomain.com/index.php?fc=module&module=mymodule&controller=api`.

How can I disable automatic redirect for a PrestaShop ModuleFrontController?

I even tried to make it independent of the PrestaShop controller-system by accessing a PHP-file in my module-dir:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config/config.inc.php');
require_once('mymodule.php');
```

Even that last approach redirects me to the new domain.

**Is there any way to disable PrestaShop redirects for a script?**

Comment: are both domains configured in prestashop? if so, how did you configured them?

Comment: @sadlyblue Prestashop redirects to what ever domain that is configured in Back-office seo and urls. Shop domain, and shop domain ssl. That is what I want to avoid. Lets say I do not "involve" Prestashop in this and just make a normal php-script not including any presta classes, then that file wil be accessible both via ´mydomain.com/myscript.php´ and ´mynewdomain.com/myscript.php´, without any redirects.

Comment: That's the normal behaviour. To use other domains, check the multistore features. Or maybe use htaccess rewrite.

Comment: I know it's the normal behaviour - I am looking for a way to bypass that behavior.

Comment: @OnklMaps There is no way to “bypass” it, it’s like if you enter in `google.com` and you will expect to see `bing.com`, at least you use an iframe.